# What is the correct HTTP Status Code for a WCF Web service to return when the request data content is well formed, but fails data validation?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, http-status

I am consuming a WCF web service. I am providing syntactically correct xml data, but one of the application specific codes provided is sometimes incorrect (correct datatype but not a valid value - passes the xsd though). The web service returns a detailed response message in the response body and an HTML Status Code of Bad Request 400. Due to the Bad Request 400 status code, the WCF web service proxy immediately raises an exception and the ResponseBody is never available to interrogate for the detailed message. The only way I can ever see the detailed validation message is to turn on web service tracing and look at the trace file (obviously that means rerunning the request and is very time consuming).

I think the Bad Request 400 status code is incorrect for this situation. What I am not clear on is what the correct status should be. Note: this is not WebAPI REST, this is WCF web service.

I think 200 OK would be fine as the actual request was well formed, but the content was invalid. Then look at the response body for the real status.

Best practice answers please.

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 2):

That would still be a 400 Status Code. The data was bad for some reason or another.

I could also see a 500 type response used as well, but it isn't necessarily unexpected data.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: I still don't agree. The service is providing bespoke detailed error messages in the responseBody, but this breaks the WS-I standard. If you are returning a responseBody, the only correct status code is 200 (OK). They are not using SOAP faults as defined in the standard. We cannot read the detailed error message without turning on tracing, rerunning the call and hunting through the trace log. This is a massive overhead for Support.

http://ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-2.0-2010-11-09.html#SOAP_Fault_Processing

Comment: Sounds like your trying to solve a logging issue. Your WCF Service should have some logging wrapped around it's exceptions and when they occur.